# Mockito different range expectations

Tags: scala, mockito, specs

I'm using Mockito as a part of Specs in scala code and I've stumbled upon the following task:
*Given an ArrayBuffer that emulates a chess board (8x8 = 64 cells). If we querying `ArrayBuffer` for cell that doesn't exist (has number more than 63 or less than 0) we should receive `None`. Otherwise we returning `Some(0)` (in almost all cases) or `Some(1)` (just in few specified cells).*

Right now I'm thinking about spies and something that starts like:

```
val spiedArray = spy(new ArrayBuffer[Int])
  for (x <- 1 to 8; y <- 1 to 8) {
    doReturn(Some(0)).when(spiedArray).apply(x * y-1)
  }
```

And then explicitly respecify cells with Some(1).
But how about out-of-bound cells that should return `None`?

Is there a simplest and natural way to achieve that mocking?

Comment: I think you should go from 0 to 7 instead of 1 to 8 ;) ... otherwise I don't really see the benefit of mocking vs populating the ArrayBuffer here ? ... would probable make more sense if you created an interface over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that the specification is wrong: an `ArrayBuffer` cannot work as expected in the spec. Thus you must either:

- Change the expected behavior
- Change `ArrayBuffer` for an homemade trait

Comment: Yeah, mocking concept was misunderstood.